# Does Amazon Japan deliver to hotels?

Tags: japan, hotels

Is it possible for travellers to Japan to buy stuff at Amazon and have it delivered to the hotel?

Comment: Is this a question about the hotels (on-topic) or about Amazon (off-topic)? To keep it on topic you need to reword it to focus on the hotel - it currently looks like it's focused on Amazon.

Comment: I'd rephrase it as 'can you get online deliveries (like Amazon) while travelling' - there may be alternatives even if Amazon itself doesn't deliver (eg relay deliveries)

Comment: I think, this should be closed until the rephrasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my friend's experience, It is possible.

However you should do arrangement with the hotel prior your arrival in the hotel.

Comment: Just curious - is this referring to Amazon.com, Amazon.co.jp, or both?

Comment: good question...